# Como listar os depedentes de um determinado funcionário com Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Olá, acontece que estou dando meus primeiros passos no Laravel. Criei um banco de dados com duas tabelas (dependentes e funcionários), criei o crud de cada uma e exibir todo o sistema no html (bootstrap). O problema é que não estou conseguindo criar uma página em que, quando clicado no botão do funcionário, vai para a lista de dependentes desse usuário. A relação é de 1 para N.

Usando o Tinker eu consigo listar, mas gostaria de exibir ele no sistema, no html (como faço com a lista geral de dependentes e de funcionários). 
Achei isso na documentação mas não obtive muitos resultados no projeto: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Funcionario extends Model {

    protected $fillable= [

        'codigo',
        'nome',
        'sexo'

    ];

    public function todosDependentes(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Dependente', 'funcionario_id', 'id');

    }
}


namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dependente extends Model{
    protected $fillable = [

        'funcionario_id',
        'nome',
        'dataNascimento'

    ];

    public function funcionario(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Funcionario',  'id', 'funcionario_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Posta os dois `Models` na sua pergunta!!!

Comment: editei a postagem

Comment: A resposta feita te esclarece, sim não e porque?

Comment: Foi sim, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu **Model Funcionario** faça isso:

```
public function todosDependentes(){
    $this->hasMany('App\Dependente');
}
```

No seu **Model Dependente** faça isso:

```
public function funcionario(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Funcionario');
}
```

Quando você passar o objeto **funcionario** para a sua `view` pelo controller...

```
public function dependentes($id){
    $funcionario = App\Funcionario::find($id);
    return view('sua_view', compact($funcionario);
}
```

Você poderá listar os dependentes da seguinte forma para mostra o `id` dos dependentes por exemplo:

```
@foreach($funcionario->todosDependentes as $dependente)
    <p>{{ $dependente->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Desculpa pelo feedback tardio, só agora pude testar. Funcionou muito bem, fico imensamente grato! Achei estranho porque da mesma forma que você fez eu tinha feito mas sempre dava erro de "Variável não declarada" na view, mas acredito que o problema era no foreach(). Mais uma vez, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @Ramones que bom que funcionou!